# nodejs http request data event not emitted

Tags: node.js

I'm using the latest v0.6.1 running on ubuntu linux

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log("******* got data ********");
  });

  request.on('end', function() {
    console.log('on end');
  });

  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(1337, "localhost");
```

I got the end event just fine, but data event is never received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind..

The data event only fires when the request has a body. Simple requests like GET have no body and therefore does not emits data event.

Comment: Just to add, 'end' event does get triggered, regardless if there's a request body or not.